# Unity Anima2D - IK Limb for leg not working

Tags: unity, animation, skeletal-animation

I'm having an issue getting an IK limb to work using Anima2D in Unity. If I place a limb IK for the neck joint, the head moves as expected, however trying to place one for the leg seems to have no effect.

A CCD IK seems to work, but only moving one bone of the leg, whereas I need both bones to move, like a real limb with a knee joint.

[image: Pic of Unity with issue highlighted]

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer: The lower bone (in my example the Left_Leg and Right_Leg) were not set as a child of the higher bone (Left_Thigh, Right_Thigh). Setting the lower bone as the child of the higher bone fixed the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted if it solved your problem.